# switch statement and getopt() function in C

Tags: c, module, makefile, switch-statement, getopt

I am trying to parse the arguments in the command line using `switch` and `getopt()`. The structure is very easy: I have a `makefile`, a `.c` and a `.h` file. This is the first time that I am using switch, so I might be doing some basic mistakes. I have used this link as my guide to switch
[link text](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt)
and
[link text](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt)
If you see any basic mistakes please let me know.

makefile:

```
make:lunar

lunar: lunar.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -g -o lunar lunar.o -lm
lunar.o: lunar.c lunar.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -g -c lunar.c

clean:
    -rm -f *.o lunar core
```

/////////////////////////////////////

lunar.c

```
int main (int argc,  char *argv[]){
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    int gravity = 0;
    int thrust = 0;
    opterr = 0;
    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "gtf:")) != -1)
        switch (c){
            case 'g':
                gravity = argv[optind];
                break;
            case 't':
                thrust = argv[optind];
                break;
            case 'f':
                argument = argv[optind];
                break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'c')
                    fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires 
                            an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option 
                             `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option 
                             character `\\x%x'.\n", 
                             optopt);
                return 1;
            defult:
                abort ();
        }
    printf ("gravity is %d and thrust is %d.\n", 
            gravity, thrust);
    for (int index = optind ; index < argc ; index++ ){
        printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////

lunar.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_WORD 256
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that '`default`' has an 'a' in it - you've just labelled that code with the (unused) label `defult`, rather than given the switch a default case.

It is not clear why you think `optopt` could be 'c' or should be treated specially when it is 'c'; it might be a hangover from an earlier edition.

You are processing the 'g' and 't' options as if they take arguments, but the call to `getopt()` does not list colons after them.  If the switch is to be believed, you need the argument to be `"g:t:f:"`.

Also, you should be using the `char *` called `optarg` instead of trying to use `argv[optind]`.  You use `optind` after the loop has finished to process extra ('file name') arguments.

Also, since `gravity` and `thrust` are integers, you need to convert the strings into integers.  The easy way (largely ignoring possible errors) is with:

```
gravity = atoi(optarg);
```

If you want to do error handling, call a function to do the checking and error reporting.

I recommend putting braces around the `switch` statement, or around the body of the `while` statement:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "g:f:t:")) != -1)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

It isn't strictly necessary, but it is (IMNSHO) easier to read the code with the extra braces.  For a single line statement, I'd have no problem; but for a complex statement like the switch, I recommend the extra braces.

The '`return 0;`' should be outside the `for` loop.  At the moment, the loop stops on the first non-option argument.

---

The makefile is basically fine.  Eventually, you'll use more macros and more compilation warning flags, but the only problems that I spotted that the compiler would also spot were the typo in the default case and the non-conversion of strings into integers.

```
PROGRAM = lunar
SOURCE  = lunar.c
HEADER  = ${SOURCE:.c=.h}
OBJECT  = ${SOURCE:.c=.o}
CFLAGS  = -std=c99 -Wall -g
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS  = -lm

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${OBJECT}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJECT} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

${OBJECT}: ${SOURCE} ${HEADER}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${SOURCE}

clean:
    -rm -f *.o ${PROGRAM} core
```